# How to find to which area a point belongs using hash maps?

Tags: algorithm, hash, geometry, cluster-analysis

Say we have a 2d space devided into clusters say via [Voronoi Tessellation](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366):

[image]

We have cluster outlines, mid points. Given a point (x, y coordinates) in such space how to take its hash so that it would allow us to determin to which cluster it belongs?

I know that we can make our clusters form a binary tree by adding layers and figure where point belongs using tree search. Also I know that we can map each space point (asuming it is descreet) to a cluster and get O(1) storing loads of data. But I seek for a way to use unordered hash map style to get a cluster from given point. How to do such thing (algorithmicly)?

Comment: I think that would only be possible if the layout was a xy axis-aligned grid. The space would be divided in even rectangles are you could just use the point xy coordinates and divide total width/height of your dataset to retrieve the rectangle its in.

Comment: Well a point I am given is located an an area closest to a midpoint, which is just a coordinate pair... May be we can sumhow build hash function out of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) over Voronoi sites (cell "centers"), and you would search the closest site in O(NlogN) time.

Note that both point and the closest site belong to the same cell due to Voronoi diagram properties

Another option - build [trapezoid decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Trapezoidal_decomposition) of cells (perhaps, more complex way)

Answer (score 0):

In the Voronoi Tessellation each "cluster" is the locus of the points that have as its nearest neighbor the corresponding mid point.

Thus, what you are interested in is actually finding the nearest neighbor (among all mid points) of a new point.

If you intend to use hashing for this purpose, maybe you should read about Locality-sensitive hashing.